# is never assigned to,and will always have its default value 0

Tags: c#

my problem is that a is never assigned to,and will have its default value 0

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int a, b, c, d, thickness;
   
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
    }

  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        Pen blackpen = new Pen(colorDialog1.Color);

        blackpen.Width = thick;
        drawline1.DrawLine(blackpen, a);
    }
```

the program run but not working its like that dosnt get numbers i gave it to it
it works like this tho

```
    {
        a = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
   
 
        drawline1.DrawLine(blackpen, a;
    }
```

Comment: These are warnings the compiler uses to tell you about unused variables. From your posted code… `b`, `c`, `d` and `thickness` are never used. The code should still run… it’s just a warning.

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: You're shadowing `a` in `textBox1_TextChanged`. By that I mean: `int a = ...` creates a new variable called `a`. That variable is completely unrelated to the field `int a` declared outside of the method. You should replace `int a = ` with `a = ` if you want to assign a value to the class-level field.

Comment: By the way, if `textBox1.Text` is empty, you'll also get an error from `Convert.ToInt16` (_"Input string was not in a correct format."_). You should either check if it's empty before performing the conversion, or (and this is the better option) use [`Int16.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16.tryparse?view=net-5.0) instead (see the link for examples on how to use this).

Comment: Based on your latest edit, it does sound like your event handler isn't linked up for textBox1_Changed, as Olivier said. Try setting a breakpoint on it to see if it gets called when you type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:

```
a = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
```

Because if you write:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
```

It creates a [local variable](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/know-scope-local-variables) named `a` that masks the class member `a` so you don't assign the class variable `a` used in the other method, but the local.

Also you should care about how you name the types, classes, members and variables to avoid such thing:

[C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md)

[General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)

[C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

For example, you may write for example:

```
int Value1;
int Value2;
int Value3;
int Value4;
int Thickness;
```

By changing `Value` with the real word that design what the data do or is used for.

Also you can manage errors thrown by `Convert` or use `int.TryParse` and show a message too.

Comment: tnx but i just noticed that and changed it but still not working

Comment: You're presumably still getting similar _warnings_ because you're not assigning values to (or indeed using) `b`, `c`, `d`, or `thickness` either. They are just that though: warnings.

Comment: @evanhansen Is the handler assigned to the textbox event using designer or by code? Maybe you lost the link, check it in the control property editor.